# Solving and plotting ODEs while varying one of the initial conditions

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, graphics3d

How can I vary an initial condition in the numerical solution of a system  of ODEs and then make a 3D plot of the solution space with that condition as one of the variables.

```
sol = NDSolve[
  {y''[t] + y'[t] + 4*y[t] + x[t] - x'[t] == 0, 
   x'[t] + 3*c*y[t] == 0,
   y[1] == 1, y'[1] == 1, 
   x[0] == 1}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

I want to vary one of the condition variables, say `y[1]` over `u = Range[-10, 10, step]`. Then I want to make a 3D plot of the solution space `(x[t[, y[t], y[1][u])`.

Can anyone please guide me in solving this query.

Comment: Your equation can be solved analytically, so you can just exchange  `y[1]==1` with `y[1]==z` and `DSolve` the equation and `Plot3D[x[t] /. sol, {t, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}]`.

Comment: @xzczd  In fact, the equation in my problem involves multipliers in terms of time, I have put the simplest form. I need a way to solve numerically.

Comment: @MuhammadZubair, have a look at `ParametricNDSolve` and see if that helps.

Comment: @ruebenko Wow, I think I'd better upgrade to v9 quickly.

Comment: @xzczd, if you need a parametric version of `NDSolve` this is it; automatic sensitivity computation. It's pretty cool, I think. Also a much better `Event` language and better DAE solving capabilities, are just a few highlights of V9 NDSolve. Hope that's enough of a teaser...

Comment: @xzczd thanks for your very valuable suggestions. I was using 7.0, now i have got the 8.0.

Comment: @m_goldberg, you have improved the format of question very well.

Comment: @ruebenko thanks for your suggestion of `ParametricNDSolve` in 9.0, i will try to find 9.0 soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Playing with @ruebenko's suggestion,

```
c = 1
pf = ParametricNDSolveValue[
  {y''[t] + y'[t] + 4*y[t] + x[t] - x'[t] == 0,
   x'[t] + 3*c*y[t] == 0, y[1] == 1,
   y'[1] == u,
   x[0] == 1}, y, {t, 0, 10}, {u \[Element] Reals}]

Plot3D[pf[u][t], {u, -10, 10}, {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

ruebenko has pointed out the best way to solve this in the comment above: use `ParametricNDSolve` in version 9. Then, I'd like to post my clumsy solution with version 8 since I've already finished it…:

```
c = 1;
zmin = -1; zmax = 1; n = 25;
tmin = -1; tmax = 1;
ex = 
 Table[Join[{z}, #] & /@ 
       Transpose[{First[(x /. First@#)["Coordinates"]], (x /. First@#)["ValuesOnGrid"]}] &@
       NDSolve[{y''[t] + y'[t] + 4 y[t] + x[t] - x'[t] == 0, 
                x'[t] + 3 c y[t] == 0, y[1] == z, y'[1] == 1, x[0] == 1}, 
               {x, y}, {t, tmin, tmax}], 
       {z, zmin, zmax, (zmax - zmin)/n}];

ListPlot3D[Flatten[ex, 1]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Just for your sample, it can be solved analytically, too:

```
c = 1;
sol = DSolve[{y''[t] + y'[t] + 4 y[t] + x[t] - x'[t] == 0, 
              x'[t] + 3 c y[t] == 0, y[1] == z, y'[1] == 1, x[0] == 1}, 
             {x, y}, {t}];
Plot3D[x[t] /. sol, {z, -1, 1}, {t, -1, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]